# About Manifest file

Tags: manifest

Recently, I encountered a very strange issue, this issue only happens in Windows XP SP3 and Vista. Here are my steps:

1. Create two new folders in desktop (assume folder names are A and B)
2. Copy Microsoft GraphEdit (`graphedt.exe`) application to A folder, then create a empty `graphedt.exe.manifest` file as well. Run `graphedt.exe`, you will see a error message, the `graphedt.exe` can’t run due to the wrong manifest.
3. Copy Microsoft GraphEdit (`graphedt.exe`) application to B folder, run `graphedt.exe` and close it, then create a empty `graphedt.exe.manifest` file, run `graphedt.exe` again, you will see the manifest file can’t apply to `graphedt.exe`. But if you change the last modified time of `graphed.exe`, the manifest will work again.

It seems Windows will remember the status the first time the EXE uses a manifest file, but also Windows will reset the old remembered status if you change the EXE size or last modified date.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[I'm the current SxS maintainer at Microsoft]

Good investigation Yigang. You're describing the behavior on Vista, not on XP SP3.

Probing for the existence of a manifest every time an app is run would be a performance issue, since usually apps either have a manifest or don't, and that state doesn't change much. For this reason, on Vista, the first time an application is run, we cache a bit describing "this application has an associated manifest" or "this application does not have a manifest". When you ran graphedt.exe the first time, Windows cached the absence of a manifest, and will subsequently not look for one. To reset the cache, update the last modified time on the executable.