# What to exclude from a Visual Studio release folder

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

I have just finished my C# Windows form program and would like to make a zip file of the binary so others can download it. I checked the bin/release folder, and while I can recognize many files which I know will be necessary, but some other files I am not sure if it is safe to exclude them.

The following files are the ones I am not so sure:

- program.pdb
- program.exe.manifest
- program.exe.config
- program.application
- ExternalDLL.xml (related to
  ExternalDLL.dll which I need to keep,
  but is the xml important?)

P.S. I am using VS Express so I have to manually deploy my project.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: You don't need any of those, with the possible exception of the .config file. If you didn't store any of the app's configuration in its .config file, then you don't need it either. I recommend excluding all of them and trying your app on a different machine. I expect it'll work fine.

The longer answer is: There's probably individual SO questions about each. For example, here's a manifest/application question: [C# - do I need manifest files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815228/c-do-i-need-manifest-files)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spend half an hour trying to search using different keywords, but couldn't find any of these :P

Comment: Just found out that it won't work on XP, so the unaccept for now.

Comment: Does it work on XP with all the files but not without the extras? The simple answer then is to start removing files (start with pdb and xml and work from there) and see what you need for it to work. Once you find out which files it needs, please reply.

Comment: Yeah a user reported that, so I included it back, and he reported that it works. Will try to find an XP machine and test it.